# $y=\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $y$ can be expanded in ascending powers of $x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $y=\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and assuming that $y$ can be expanded in ascending powers of $x$ in the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+....+a_nx^n$... prove that $(n+1)a_{n+1}=na_{n-1}$

How to proceed in this question? Is it possible to write $y=\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ in ascending powers of x?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$y\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin^{-1}x$$

Differentiating both sides wrt $x$

$$y_1\sqrt{1-x^2}-y\cdot\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$\iff(1-x^2)y_1-xy=1$$

As $y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_rx^r, y_1=\sum_{r=1}^\infty ra_rx^{r-1}$

Compare the coefficients of $x^{r+2}$